# Can someone explain what the values are and where they are found?

Tags: bare-metal, board-leds

I'm trying to follow along with [this](https://github.com/BrianSidebotham/arm-tutorial-rpi/blob/master/part-2/armc-06/) OS building tutorial.

I'm trying to understand what the `LED_` values in `rpi-gpio.h` mean and how they are all used. Where in the documentation are these values listed? I tried looking at the PDFs but I just don't know where to find them.

What are the values and how are they used? Where are they from?

Comment: Please don't expect us to search for the question.  Add the relevant bit(s) of `rpi-gpio.h` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, those `#define` statements are assigning human-readable names to the GPIO pins, as documented for the Pi.

See [the official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf), scroll to page 90.